# Open a hyperlink on IE on Windows 8

Tags: xaml, windows-8

this might question might sounds stupid, but I could'nt figure it out. How can I open a hyperlink to IE externally on metro style app.

Something like WebBrowserTask on windows phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Windows.System.Launcher to invoke whatever app the user has configured for a given URI (no guarantee that it's IE).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.launcher.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot. exactly what I wanted. (LaunchUriAsync)